# Laravel saving polymorphic model doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphic-associations

I'm working on a Laravel 9 project. I'm new to Polymorphic relationships and believe I need to define one.

In my application, I have a parent model called `Application` that has a single `ApplicationGBPayday` model, but it could have other models in the future for different products/countries.

I've defined my `Application` model schema to contain a `modelable` morph fieldset, and in my controller where I create an `Application` I then need to create and link the `ApplicationGBPayday`, but I'm getting an error right now:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'modelable_type' doesn't have a default value

My controller I'm doing:

```php
// create application
$application = Application::create([
    'user_id' => $affiliate->user_id,
    'company_id' => $affiliate->company_id,
    'country_id' => $affiliate->affiliate_product->country->id,
    'product_id' => $affiliate->affiliate_product->product->id,
    'serve_method_id' => $affiliate->affiliate_product->serve_method->id,
    'application_form_id' => $affiliate->affiliate_product->application_form->id,
    'pingtree_group_id' => $affiliate->affiliate_product->pingtree_group->id,
    'affiliate_id' => $affiliate->id,
    'thread_uuid' => $threadUUID,
    'status' => 'pending',
    'submitted_at' => $submittedAt
]);

$payday = ApplicationGBPayday::create($request->all());
```

And here's my model for `Application`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use App\Casts\Json;

class Application extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'applications';

    /**
     * The attributes that aren't mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = [];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'submitted_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    /**
     * Get the parent modelable model.
     */
    public function modelable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

And `ApplicationGBPayday`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Casts\Json;

class ApplicationGBPayday extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'application_gb_paydays';

    /**
     * The attributes that aren't mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = [];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'buyer_list' => Json::class,
        'buyer_list_pending' => Json::class,
        'buyer_list_accepted' => Json::class,
        'buyer_list_declined' => Json::class,
        'buyer_list_invalid' => Json::class,
        'buyer_list_skipped' => Json::class,
        'other_data_json' => Json::class,
        'response_json' => Json::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Get the model's application
     */
    public function application()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Application::class, 'modelable');
    }
}
```

I'm struggling to figure out how to save the morph fields since they can't be null here, yet I need the application created first and then the payday? What am I missing?

#### UPDATE

I've tried:

```php
// create application
$application = Application::create([
    'user_id' => $affiliate->user_id,
    'company_id' => $affiliate->company_id,
    'country_id' => $affiliate->affiliate_product->country->id,
    'product_id' => $affiliate->affiliate_product->product->id,
    'serve_method_id' => $affiliate->affiliate_product->serve_method->id,
    'application_form_id' => $affiliate->affiliate_product->application_form->id,
    'pingtree_group_id' => $affiliate->affiliate_product->pingtree_group->id,
    'affiliate_id' => $affiliate->id,
    'thread_uuid' => $threadUUID,
    'status' => 'pending',
    'submitted_at' => $submittedAt
]);

$payday = new ApplicationGBPayday($request->all());
$application->modelable()->save($payday);
```

Which gives me:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'modelable_type' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `applications`

Comment: Try with this code for save morph relationship data.
`$payday = new ApplicationGBPayday($request->all());
$application->modelable()->save($payday);`

Comment: `modelable_type` and `modelable_id` are on my `Application` model which comes before the Payday, so would this still be ok?

Comment: Yes, If my code is working fine for resolving your issue then it is ok

Comment: Hi @NIKUNJKOTHIYA Ok so I tried your code, and as anticipated, I get the same error. See my updated post. The `Application` model needs the modelable type, but I don't know how it can ever have this without me creating my payday first, but my payday needs the application id too.